# Django - How to save files to STATIC_ROOT from views?

Tags: python, django, python-imaging-library

I have made a Django app that takes arguments from the form and makes an image using Pillow.

views.py:

```
file_name = "{}.png".format(random.randint(1, 255))
image1.save(file_name)
```

pretty simple stuff, right? Now when I try to render that image with HttpResponse as:

```
return HttpResponse("<img src='" +file_name + "' alt='image here'>")
```

apparently, it will throw an error. Can you please tell me what to do in order to save it properly and show in HttpResponse?

Django==1.11.8

Pillow==5.0.0

Python 3.6.2

Thank you!

Comment: It'd be helpful if you can guide me to add that image to the model database as ImageField.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you should be saving to MEDIA_ROOT. Secondly, you need to put an actual URL - ie relative to MEDIA_URL - in your img src, not just a filename. Third, you need to have something serving files at that URL.

Comment: Yes, I should be saving to MEDIA_ROOT but how?

Comment: By passing the full path into the Pillow save method.